# OnValidate - registering lots of different validations

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I wrote a GUI tool which has a lot of variables that can be changed via entrys.
Every entry has a different validation rule and I only show around 20 items per page (array of entries). I fear that when I register too many validations (on TK) without unregistering (?) before switching to the next page my program will crash sooner or later because it stacks? If yes, how can I unregister?

```
def is_ascii(s):
  try:
    s.decode('ascii')
  except (UnicodeDecodeError,UnicodeEncodeError) :
      return False          
  else:
      return True          

def OnValidate2(i,P,S,char=0,signed=0,bits=0):
  if char:
    if int(i)==0 :
      return is_ascii(S)
    else: return False
  elif signed:
    pass # more to follow

vcmd2 = (root.register(OnValidate2),'%i', '%P','%S',1)
ent = Entry(root, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd2)  #unregister ??
```

Comment: did you get any error so far?

Comment: No, i did not finish the code yet but i´m sure root.register does not overwrite (else multiple validations wouldn´t be possible i guess). I think i read about this issue somewhere but its too long ago to remember. Even if i test it and it "works" it might not on other systems having way resources, i´m sure there is a method to unregister theese, just don´t know where to look (haven´t even found description of  what register() does)

Comment: Why do you have this fear? Have you read something that is leading you to this conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about it. There is no need to unregister a validation function. Bear in mind you only need to define and register a given function once. Once `OnValidate2` has been registered, you can use it with as many widgets as you want.

It seems rather odd to have dozens of different validation functions. You might want to consider combining several into a general purpose routine. For example, if you have one that checks for one bit and one that checks for two, you can have a single function that works for either.

Here's an example showing how you register a single command and use it with several different parameters:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        cmd = root.register(self._validate)

        row = 0
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        for char in (0,1):
            for signed in (0,1):
                for bits in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7):
                    txt = "char: %s signed: %s bits: %2s:" % (char, signed, bits)
                    vcmd = (cmd, "%i", "%P", "%S", char, signed, bits)
                    label = tk.Label(self, text=txt)
                    entry = tk.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
                    label.grid(row=row, column=0)
                    entry.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky="ew")
                    row += 1

    def _validate(self, i,P,S, char=0, signed=0, bits=0):
        print "validating char=", char, "signed=", signed, "bits=", bits,
        print "P=", P, "i=", i, "S=", S
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! That´s exactly what i am trying to do (char=0,signed=0,bits=0) but i have to call root.register for every entry since the variables have lots of different types (int4, uint2, char) and thats why i feared i will get problems because of registering too many validations (even doubling when viewing the same page again, just 20 entries as table in an array which need to be reconfigured per page). I could find out all different types and register only theese but i made a .csv which has all the info about the vars which i´d like to use to determine the onvalidate params

Comment: @MarcPole: I've updated my answer to include an example of how to register a single command and use it with multiple widgets.

Comment: Thank you very much, now i understand how to do it properly and your example is very good for testing out my onvalidate func :) Just can´t give you credit cuz i don´t have enough rep :(